# queueSender.send when reach max q depth

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using queueSender.send(msg) to send the message to destination q. Here q session is not transactional and queueSender's delivery mode is default mode [i believe default is PERSISTENT]. What will happend if application is still sending message when the q has reached the max q depth.  Is there any issue with the app performance? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Performance turn the receiving application to make sure it keeps up with the message flow.
2. Increase the receiving application's queue from a default depth of 5000 to 200000 (or some really large value)
3. Make sure the sending application can handle a reason code of 2053 (MQRC_Q_FULL).  i.e. pause the application or put the messages to another queue.

Updated:

If you are using JMS when you put a message to a full queue, you will get a JMS exception: JMSWMQ2007.  If the JMSException is not null then get the LinkedException.
i.e.

```
catch (JMSException e)
{
   System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
   if (e != null)
      System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
}
```

And the error messages should look like:

> JMSWMQ2007: Failed to send a message to destination 'TEST.Q25'.
>   getLinkedException()=com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ
>   call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2053'
>   ('MQRC_Q_FULL').

Comment: Thanks Roger for your reply. I am using std javax jms api, not IBM MQ specific to connect to the MQ. Here the QueueSession created using AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE. If i am trying push more messages after reaching the max q depth, is this going to create blocking threads? Also i am not getting any exception also.

Comment: @Roger
Does this cause Timeout exception?

Comment: No. Queue full RC of 2053 has nothing to do with a time out.  Actually, MQ does not have a timeout issue, unless you are talking about MQGET and RC of 2033.

Answer (score 0):

**Find the value of the maxdepth (Maximum queue depth) parameter**

```
display qlocal(<QUEUENAME>)
```

**Alter maxdepth value (0-999999999)**

```
alter qlocal(<QUEUENAME>) maxdepth(<DEPTH>)
```